# Extracting STL Map from Boost Property Tree

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I understand that `boost::property_tree::ptree` may contain key-value pairs where the 'value' may be of any type. Now my question is that, now my 'value' is a `std::map`, and when I attempt to `pt.get<std::map<std::string, std::string>>` where `pt` is a property tree, I get a compile time error. Hence, my question is:

**How to extract a STL map value from a boost property tree? If this is not possible, is there any way of converting between STL map and boost property tree (so that each node of the property tree is not a STL container but a simple data type)**.

Comment: Post a [example] and the full, unedited error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d54fabc4a1c8138)**

```
ptree pt;

std::map<std::string, ptree> m(pt.begin(), pt.end());
```

However, note that keys need not be unique:

```
std::multimap<std::string, ptree> mm(pt.begin(), pt.end());
```

And if you are want to transform all values to `std::string` (assuming they all have a string value):

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> dict;
for (auto& [k,v]: pt) {
    dict.emplace(k, v.get_value<std::string>());
}
```

### Side-By-Side Comparisoon

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/d4aE3o)**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

template<> struct fmt::formatter<ptree> : fmt::formatter<std::string>
{
    template<typename Ctx>
    auto format(ptree const& pt, Ctx& ctx) {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "'{}'", pt.get_value<std::string>());
    }
};

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    pt.put("keyA", "valueA-1");
    pt.put("keyB", "valueB");
    pt.put("keyC", "valueC");

    pt.add("keyA", "valueA-2"); // not replacing same key
    
    std::map<std::string, ptree> m(pt.begin(), pt.end());
    std::multimap<std::string, ptree> mm(pt.begin(), pt.end());

    std::map<std::string, std::string> dict;
    for (auto& [k,v]: pt) {
        dict.emplace(k, v.get_value<std::string>());
    }

    fmt::print(
        "map:\n\t{}\n"
        "multimap:\n\t{}\n"
        "dict:\n\t{}\n",
        fmt::join(m, "\n\t"),
        fmt::join(mm, "\n\t"),
        fmt::join(dict, "\n\t")
    );
}
```

Prints

```
map: 
        ("keyA", 'valueA-1')
        ("keyB", 'valueB')
        ("keyC", 'valueC')
multimap:
        ("keyA", 'valueA-1')
        ("keyA", 'valueA-2')
        ("keyB", 'valueB')
        ("keyC", 'valueC')
dict:
        ("keyA", "valueA-1")
        ("keyB", "valueB")
        ("keyC", "valueC")
```

### BONUS: Ptree From String Dictionary

[added `ptree_from_map` function](https://godbolt.org/z/619sWz)

```
template <typename MapLike>
ptree ptree_from_map(MapLike const& m) {
    ptree pt;
    for (auto const& [k,v]: m) {
        pt.add(k, v);
    }
    return pt;
}
```

Comment: Oh, noticed you wanted the reverse as well: [added `ptree_from_map` function](https://godbolt.org/z/619sWz)

Comment: 1) I think you've mis-understood the question. OP has maps as values in the property tree, he/she does not want to convert the property tree into a map

2) This doesn't work anyway, if you have more than one level of nodes in your tree.

Comment: @Dan It's clearly you who is misreading the question. Yes, from the perspective of a general purpose tree datastructure (Property Tree) you're quite right. OP is _explicitly_ asking to store/retrieve a map from a single key. You could even do it using say `boost::json::serialize`. In fact, I discourage people to use Boost Property Tree - have been for at least a decade. (PS: If you have a related question I'm happy to answer it, just post a new question!)