# Can't get_value() from Boost property tree map value in VS2019

Tags: boost

I followed this link to extract a Boost property tree value.

[Extracting STL Map from Boost Property Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978675/extracting-stl-map-from-boost-property-tree)

I don't have library fmt installed so just modified the output function from the original code. The code works fine in g++. But when testing in VS2019, the error "identifier "" is undefined" kept popping.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    pt.put("keyA", "valueA-1");
    pt.put("keyB", "valueB");
    pt.put("keyC", "valueC");

    pt.add("keyA", "valueA-2"); // not replacing same key
    
    std::map<std::string, ptree> m(pt.begin(), pt.end());
    std::multimap<std::string, ptree> mm(pt.begin(), pt.end());

    std::map<std::string, std::string> dict;
    for (auto& [k,v]: pt) {                           // THIS LINE HAS ERROR!
        dict.emplace(k, v.get_value<std::string>());
    }

    for (auto elem : dict) {
        std::cout << elem.first << "  "  << elem.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with this specified line so I must have missed some switches or config in VS2019?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer myself after realizing VS2019 uses C++14 by default. The specified line: "auto& [k, v] : pt" needs some C++17 feature. So go to Project Setting --> Configuration Properties --> General --> C++ Language Standard --> Change to ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17).

Then the code works fine